# How to bind Jquery function to click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written this function:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.loaderHolder = function(action){
        var loaderHolder = $(document.createElement('div'))
                                .addClass('loaderHolder'),
            safeImage = $(document.createElement('img'))
                            .attr("src", "/static/images/icons/vault-bg.svg")
                            .addClass("safe"),
            lockImage = $(document.createElement('img'))
                            .attr("src", "/static/images/icons/vault-lock.svg")
                            .addClass("lock"),
            loader = loaderHolder.append(safeImage, lockImage);

        return this.each(function(){
            if(action === "add"){
                $(this).append(loader); 
            } else if(action === "remove"){
                $(this).children('.loaderHolder').remove();
            };
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This function generates or deletes a loader. I can run the function like this: `$('.foo').loaderHolder('add');`.

But if I want to add loaders to elements which are dynamically generated, I need to write my code like this:

```
$('.holder').on('click', '.foo', function(){
   $(this).loaderHolder('add'); 
});
```

I really don't like the anonymous function. Is there any other way to write this without the anonymous function?

Thanks!

Edit: thanks for all the responses. Edited my code to be correct, forgot the use the parent-selector in the dynamically-generated part.

But I was just wondering about a markup something like this:

```
$('.holder').on('click', '.foo', {action: 'add'}, $(this).loaderHolder);
```

I know this is wrong, but is there any way to do it right like this? Or do you just need to anonymous function?

Comment: What's the issue with an anonymous function?

Comment: @Filype Writing extra line of code

Comment: That's the way it's *supposed* to be done!

Answer (score 2):

Give function name in place of anonymous function

```
$('.foo').on('click', youfun);
```

For dynamically added elements you need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('staticParentSelector').on('click', '.foo', youfun);
```

[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.